# syncing 1 iOS codebase with multiple versions of corresponding server-side deployments

Tags: ios, deployment, saas

We currently have a .NET SaaS web app with individual deployments per customer. We are on a monthly release schedule and each customer is upgraded to current releases on independent schedules. Sometimes a certain member might even skip an entire release, upgrading on the subsequent release.

We are looking to develop a native iOS application and are trying to figure out the best way to keep a single iOS codebase in sync with multiple supported server-side deployments. I know that Citrix ran into this with GoToMeeting because at one point there were multiple versions of their native app in the App Store to satisfy customers with a variety of server-side versions. Supporting multiple releases corresponding to currently supported server-side deployments in the App Store is not an option we are considering. We have discussed having conditional branches in the code to check which version of the server-side code the customer is using and disabling more current code and features for those users, but this isn't ideal either. Certainly others (such as Citrix) have run into this and have come up with cleaner solutions so I thought I'd cast my net and see what responses I could get. Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with differences in API versions I would think a configuration file on your iOS app is essential. By configuration file I mean a plist or just settings download that fires when the app runs and tells it where to go for api's. This lets you do what you need with other api versions and when you are ready you can just change the configuration and point it at new versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, we are planning to use a plist to manage the service urls. I'm talking more about new features that rely on the lastest build. Meaning if the user updated their iOS app before they had updated on the server side the app would not work properly. Does that make sense? So it's not just about pointing at new versions of the back-end services, it's showing views or trying to pull data in a new version of the iOS app if the back-end hasn't been updated yet to support those new features and managing this.